# Can I improve the poor performance of the Rust zip crate?

Tags: performance, rust

Here is my benchmark program:

```
extern crate zip;

use std::fs::File;
use std::io::copy;
use zip::write::FileOptions;
use zip::ZipWriter;

fn main() {
    let mut src = File::open("/tmp/src.mxf").unwrap(); // 624 Mb file.
    let dest = File::create("/tmp/test.zip").unwrap();
    let mut zip_writer = ZipWriter::new(dest);

    zip_writer
        .start_file("src.mxf", FileOptions::default())
        .unwrap();
    copy(&mut src, &mut zip_writer).unwrap();

    zip_writer.finish().unwrap();
}
```

With the program compiled in release mode:

```
time ./zip_bench
./zip_bench  62,68s user 146,21s system 99% cpu 3:28,91 total
```

The same file compressed using the system `zip` binary:

```
time zip /tmp/test2.zip /tmp/src.mxf
zip /tmp/test2.zip /tmp/src.mxf  13,77s user 0,19s system 99% cpu 13,965 total
```

The time factor between the system and Rust zip is around 14x (for a similar output file, with insignificant size difference).

Am I doing something wrong in the code that could explain Rust performance? How can I improve it to approach system performance?

Comment: I would try to set the level of compression. Just because the final file-size is similar doesn't mean that the compression levels are similar if the file is not very compressible. Also performance not being optimal is explicitly mentioned here [`The current implementation is still a bit lacking speed-wise compared to C-libraries like zlib and miniz.`](https://docs.rs/deflate/0.7.19/deflate/). So maybe using zlib with some ffi might help out.

Comment: Tried to use `CompressionMethod::Stored` (no compression): no performance gain!
Also tried to reimplement `copy` (increasing buffer size, at 8k by default): again, no performance gain.

Comment: Curious. But it seems like you're not the only one with the issue: https://github.com/mvdnes/zip-rs/issues/88

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your `File`s in `BufReader`/`BufWriter`?

Comment: @Jmb Thanks, it helped a lot. With `BufWriter`, compression becomes 3x slower than native zip command, which is a great improvement.

Comment: @BenoitCourtine did you also add the `BufReader`? Buffering on both sides is important to get performant I/O.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have your test data, so I'm operating on a 3.7 GB Debian DVD ISO. I'm also assuming whatever you're calling the "system zip" is roughly the same as the Arch [zip package.](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/zip/)

Starting with your original code, updates to the zip crate such as moving to flate2 over deflate help:

```
time ./zipbench 

real    2m29.285s
user    2m23.396s
sys     0m4.066s
```

```
time zip test2.zip  debian-10.4.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso 
  adding: debian-10.4.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso (deflated 1%)

real    1m42.709s
user    1m38.066s
sys     0m3.386s
```

The zip utility is only about twice as fast, and we haven't even changed our code yet, just updated our crates and Rust proper by about a year.

We can add buffered IO to our Rust with `BufReader` and `BufWriter`:

```rust
fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut src = BufReader::new(File::open("./debian-10.4.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso")?);
    dest = BufWriter::new(File::create("./test.zip")?);
    let mut zip_writer = ZipWriter::new(dest);

    zip_writer.start_file("src.mxf", FileOptions::default())?;
    // This is only workable because we're only writing one file to our ZIP.
    let mut zip_writer = BufWriter::new(zip_writer);
    io::copy(&mut src, &mut zip_writer)?;

    Ok(())
}
```

This earns us a small performance bump, but not a huge amount:

```
time ./zipbench

real    2m25.348s
user    2m20.105s
sys     0m3.894s
```

You might get a bit more speed by using flate2 directly, especially if you can use [CloudFlare's Zlib fork.](https://crates.io/crates/cloudflare-zlib-sys) However, I haven't tested this.